# How is the background color to switch to Click Square?

Tags: html, colors, background

I have this code:

```
<body>

<DIV id="div1" style="position:absolute;
      top:0px;left:0px;width:320px;height:210px;">
    <DIV style="background-color:#DB97F2;position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;
                width:90px;height:90px"></div>
    <DIV style="background-color:blue;position:absolute;top:10px;left:110px;
                width:90px;height:90px"></DIV>
    <DIV style="background-color:yellow;position:absolute;top:10px;left:210px;
                width:90px;height:90px"></DIV>
    <DIV style="background-color:#DB5432;position:absolute;top:110px;left:10px;
                width:90px;height:90px"></DIV>
    <DIV style="background-color:red;position:absolute;top:110px;left:110px;
                width:90px;height:90px"></DIV>
    <DIV style="background-color:green;position:absolute;top:110px;left:210px;
                width:90px;height:90px"></DIV>
</DIV>
```

I would like to change wallpaper by clicking on the colored squares.
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETzcU.png)

The background color should be the color of each square.[example: clicking on the blue square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IJDE.png)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hi. To make your html code interactive, you might want to have a look at Javascript. There are several great tutorials online! However, a specific javascript resource that might be useful, would be jQuery. Good luck!

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I were told it I can not use jQuery .

Comment: This smells a lot like an assignment. We wouldn't want to deprive you of the thrill of working it out, but a hint in HTML5 would involve [events](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

Comment: Okey then. What are the restrictions that do you have? That you cannot use javascript, or jQuery only?

Comment: Indeed it is an activity that I need to resolve .
The slogan says not only use jQuery .
I do not want to solve the activity.
I just need to know that I can use, because then says "Where would place the event handler function ?. "

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look into javascript and it's framework JQuery to add interactivity in your webpages but of you already have prior knowledge of any JQuery this is how you would do it:

```
$('#yourSquare').click(function () {
    $('body').css("background-color", "blue"); // Just add any color you wis
});
```

Do this for all the squares which will change the background color of your page just change the divs in the selectors to correspond with your square.

link if you want to learn javascript :
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp)

Hope this helped :)